# Missing RAM and Unsupported hardware driver issue

Tags: fglrx

In a bottom right corner, appear a logo "AMD Unsupportde hardware".
I've tryed to follow some procedure (`sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates` --- then  `reboot`) but doesn't disappear.

Ubuntu find drivers by it-self, "fgrlx ATI/AMD" and ""fgrlx ATI/AMD" post-release" but I can install only the first... the second one, failed during installation procedure.

Do you have any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I've **solved** the **2nd problem** whit this driver:  http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English

Answer (score 2):

1. **Missing RAM**

   Your mother board has on board video card. Those "missing" memory are assigned to your video card. The amount should be changeable in bios.
2. **Driver for Unsupported Hardware**

   I do not have ATI/AMD video card around to test. However, my guess is you only need to install one driver, assuming both are video card driver.

Answer (score 0):

From AMD on this subject:

Response and Service Request History:

I do not have any information on the driver installed. Please note that this issue has been resolved with our latest CAT 13.1 driver.

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English

If you still encountering this problem, please provide the report from atigetsysteminfo.sh command.

In order to update this service request, please respond, leaving the service request reference intact.

Best regards,

AMD Global Customer Care